# React Router v4 routes with parameters not rendering/refreshing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios, react-router-v4

I have a route for dynamic parameters. For example when the url is `my-app.com/about` it will fetch JSON data from a REST API for the about page. I'm using one component named Page for all the URL parameters.

When I click the nav links the url changes but new content isn't rendered unless I refresh the page.

My code:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>

                <NavLink to='/home'>Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink to='/about'>About</NavLink>
                <NavLink to='/contact'>Contact</NavLink>                 

                <Switch>                                                                  
                  <Route path="/:slug" component={ Page } />                                    
                </Switch>

            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>

    );
  }
}
```

My Page component. I'm fetching JSON to render page content:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Page extends Component {

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        page: []
      };
    }

  componentDidMount() { 
    axios.get('http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=' + this.props.match.params.slug)
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ page: response.data });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <h2>Single Page template</h2>
        {this.state.page.map(single => {
            return(
            <div>
              <h1>{single.title.rendered}</h1>
              <p>{single.content.rendered}</p>
            </div>                                        
            );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Page;
```

How can I render new data in the router when I click different links? Without reloading the page in my the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is only run when the component is mounted, and when the URL changes the `slug` variable will change, but the component will not be unmounted and mounted again.

You will have to check if the `slug` parameter has changed in `componentDidUpdate` and fetch your data if that is the case.

**Example**

```
class Page extends Component {
  state = {
    page: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPageData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.match.params.slug !== this.props.match.params.slug) {
      this.getPageData();
    }
  }

  getPageData = () => {
    axios
      .get(`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=${this.props.match.params.slug}`)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ page: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  // ...
}
```

Comment: whats the point of tagging js in all the react specific question, how a geek guy of js but not comfortable with react can help in this :) btw your doing great, saw the graph its amazing :)

Comment: @MayankShukla Thanks. I think there is quite some JavaScript overlap, and it also gives syntax highlighting. But you're right, not really for this particular question.